# Why in svelte-kit's load function a valid route can't be resolved when code runs on the server

Tags: node.js, sveltekit

In my svelte-kit application I was struggeling with this NODE error [ERR_INVALID_URL](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#err_invalid_url) but was able to fix it with a solution provided in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195918/723709). Unfortunately a deeper explanation as of why NODE can't parse the url - which is obviously only a valid route when the code runs on the client - was  ommitted.

In svelte-kit's `load` function I'm implicitly `fetch` -ing an, from nodejs' perspective, invalid url (ERR_INVALID_URL)

So what I'd love to understand is, WHY does NODE fail to resolve/parse the given url?

Prerequisits:

```js
// in $lib/utils/http.js
export function post(endpoint, data = {}) {
    return fetch(endpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }).then((r) => r.json());
}

// in routes/auth/login.js -> this endpoint can't be be found by NODE
export async function post({ locals, request }) {
    // ...code here
    return {
        body: request.json()
    }
}
```

Here the distinction has to be made of whether the code runs on the client or on the server:

```js
// in routes/login.svelte
import { browser } from '$app/env';
import { post } from '$lib/utils/http.js';

export async function load() {
    const { data } = someDataObject;
    if (browser) { // NODE wouldn't be able to find the endpoint in question ('/auth/login'), whereas the client does 
        return await post(`/auth/login`, { data }).then((response) => {
            // ...do something with the response
        });
    }
    return {};
}
```

Thanks for any explanation that sheds some light into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor your `load` function to use the `fetch` provided by SvelteKit. This will allow you to use relative requests on the server, which normally requires an origin. From [the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading#input-fetch) (emphasis mine):

> fetch is equivalent to the native fetch web API, with a few additional
> features:
>
> - it can be used to make credentialed requests on the server, as it inherits the cookie and authorization headers for the page request
> - **it can make relative requests on the server (ordinarily, fetch requires a URL with an origin when used in a server context)**
> - requests for endpoints go direct to the handler function during server-side rendering, without the overhead of an HTTP call
> - during server-side rendering, the response will be captured and inlined into the rendered HTML
> - during hydration, the response will be read from the HTML, guaranteeing consistency and preventing an additional network request

So, get the `fetch` from the parameter passed to load...

```js
export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const { data } = someDataObject;
    return await post(`/auth/login`, fetch, { data }).then((response) => {
        // ...do something with the response
    });
}
```

... and use it in your `post` function

```js
// in $lib/utils/http.js
export function post(endpoint, fetch, data = {}) { /* rest as before */ }
```

A [future enhancement to SvelteKit](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2979) may make it so you don't have to pass `fetch` to your utility function, but this is what you have to do for now.

Comment: Thx Geoff for your fast reply. That did the trick!